# В чем разница между <?php и <?

Tags: php

В некоторых случаях встречаю открытие php в таком виде `<?php`, в других в таком `<?`. Есть ли разница между этими вариантами?

Comment: Используйте `<?php` и не заморачивайтесь - сокращение в новых версиях по умолчанию больше не поддерживается.

Comment: @Эдуард, вроде `short_open_tag` не удалён в новых частях саги.

Comment: Требование [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) запрещает короткие тэги.

Comment: @Other я их спутал вот с чем: `ASP-теги <%, %>, <%=, и теги скриптов <script language="php"> удалены из PHP 7`

Comment: @Other, он разве может что-то требовать? Он всего-лишь рекомендует.

Comment: @Visman, как и любой стандарт, он, разумеется, лишь рекомендует. Но глупо не следовать ему, поэтому вряд ли есть более-менее толковые разработчики, которые именно требуют следовать (как от других, так и от самих себя). ИМХО, конечно.